# Jquery animation not obeying delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of `<li>` in which I have a couple `<article>` elements. 
When I click on any `<article>` I want all of them to slide out of view one by one.

HTML is:

```
<li>
  <article class="classname">
  <article class="classname">
</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
```

the jquery function i was writing was:

```
$(".classname").click(function(){

        $(this).parent().parent().find('li').each(function(index, item){
            $(item).children().animate({ "left" : "-1000px" }).delay(2000);

        })
    })
```

the issue is when i click on any article element, all the elements slide out of view at once. Not one by one as I desire. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay function delays execution of subsequent items in the queue: you need the delay before the animate call with a staggered duration:

```
$(item).children().delay(index * 2000).animate({ "left" : "-1000px" });
```

Comment: delay in this position will actually "pause" the looping? i wasn't aware of any jquery method to pause, this is very useful. thank you

Comment: @JohnnyCraig: It doesn't pause anything. It asynchronously *delays* the execution. Notice that rich.okelly included `index * 2000`. This means that each delay will be 2000ms longer than the previous. `0 * 2000`, `1 * 2000`, `2 * 2000`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To animate items one by one you need to set different `delay` for each article:

```
$(item).children().delay(index * 2000).animate({ "left" : "-1000px" });
```

**Update**

Probably you are looking for somethign like this:

```
$(".classname").click(function(){
    $(".classname").each(function(index, item){
        $(this).delay(index * 100).animate({ "left" : "-1000px", opacity: "0" }, 500)
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3YS3/1/

Comment: this is a very simple solution, I was writing something much more complicated.

Comment: This isn't correct. It suffers the same mistake as the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`delay()` appends a delay to the queue.
You need to put in the delay *before* the animation, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your .delay() before the .animate():

```
$(item).children().delay(2000).animate({ "left" : "-1000px" });
```

Answer (score 0):

First call `.delay()` and then the animate function:

```
$(item).children().delay(2000).animate({ "left" : "-1000px" });
```

A very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/EzMzy/